# Anyway to create tweets on Twitter (X) without the use of API keys?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm an aspiring programmer looking to create a NodeJs script which simply makes a tweet on Twitter without needing API Keys (consumer key, consumer secret etc etc).

I am able to get basic authentication information like password & accesstoken, but getting API keys is just a big hassle.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a better solution than using scraper tools such as Cheerio, Puppeteer, or Cypress to navigate through the post-tweet flow. I adopted this approach when I didn't have access to the Facebook API.